# Document Construction Api

Tags: api, http, node.js, coffeescript, document

I'm currently building a API service that accepts Input in HTTP Requests, processes the information, uses a template engine (Currently Jade) to parse the Template files and then outputs in either HTML, PDF or a Image.

I would like to have this service not be bound to a Database, as I don't see a need for it. The service has one goal, accept input and output the result in the desired format.

Currently I can't decide on how to store and read my templates, it's a new world without a database....

Do I store them in a folder such as "templates" which I read each time I want a list of templates ? But have no idea how and if file locks will cause problems ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Express.js it will allow you to set up a project with a good default directory structure.  By default it stores Jade templates in 'views'.  There will be no problems with file locking.

One other thing I would do is separate the API service from the view rendering.  At the moment I use restify for pure REST services it is specifically geared toward that use case.  So the workflow would roughly look as follows

'views' folder <--> Jade templates <--> Express <--> JSON data <--> REST API

Comment: Yes my current framework is Express.js, so you are recommending that I put the template logic views in the views folder for express ?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by 'template logic'.  Templates should just be used for rendering views to the extent possible there should be no business logic

Comment: Templates in my case would be like plugins. So each template represents a diffrent layout that the service could produce.

Comment: Templates will work fine for what you're trying to do.  Just read them from the disk

Comment: Thanks for the input, just went with a hardcoded method where I set them in a array in a .coffee file.